# Converting Layered Object as JSON and back via Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, stringify

I'm trying to save a state in my program.

There is one large Array of GameAssets. Various assets can be cards, dice, and other game pieces. Each Card may have one or more CardFaces, and each CardFace has Texts and Images.

There will be more pieces later, but that's enough for now.

GameAssets is an object array that gives this:
[PokerCard]
0:PokerCard {location: Vertex, dimensions: Vertex, locked: false, direction: 0, faces: Array(2), …}
...

JSON.stringify(gameAssets) yields

```
[
   {
      "location":{
         "x":0.5,
         "y":0.25
      },
      "dimensions":{
         "x":6.25,
         "y":8.75
      },
      "locked":false,
      "direction":0,
      "faces":[
         {
            "textFields":[
               {
                  "text":"Sword",
                  "location":{
                     "x":0.5,
                     "y":0.5
                  },
                  "dimensions":{
                     "x":1,
                     "y":1
                  },
                  "fontSize":1,
                  "align":"center",
                  "color":"black"
               }
            ],
            "backgroundColor":"white",
            "border":{
               "width":1,
               "color":"black"
            },
            "location":{
               "x":0.5,
               "y":0.25
            },
            "dimensions":{
               "x":6.25,
               "y":8.75
            }
         },
         {
            "textFields":[

            ],
            "backgroundColor":"gray",
            "border":{
               "width":1,
               "color":"black"
            },
            "location":{
               "x":0.5,
               "y":0.25
            },
            "dimensions":{
               "x":6.25,
               "y":8.75
            }
         }
      ],
      "activeFace":0,
      "orientation":"Portrait"
   }
]
```

and finally JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(gameAssets)) gives back 
{location: {…}, dimensions: {…}, locked: false, direction: 0, faces: Array(2), …}

How do I maintain my objects properly, where

```
x == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x))
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you format your variable a bit for easier read?

Comment: Is your intent  saving  json object status into string, and restore it object later on browser?

Comment: Remember that `x == JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x)) ` is never going to work; even if the objects appear to be identical...  as `x` is not a value type in this case

Comment: @sungyong - Thats' correct.

Comment: @ne1410s - so how do I go about saving this complex data file?

Comment: Or do I have to go through each one, display the kind of item, and meticulously translate it from a big array to individual data items?